# Change ListView background - strange behaviour

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, background-image

I have a problem with changing the background of a view in a ListView.

**What I need:**
Change the background image of a row onClick()

**What actually happens:**
The background gets changed (selected) after pressing e.g. the first entry. But after scrolling down the 8th entry is selected too.
Scroll back to the top the first isn't selected anymore. The second entry is selected now.
Continue scrolling and it continues jumping...

**What i'm dong in the Code:**
I have channels, and onClick() I toggle an attribute of channel **boolean selected**
and then I change the background.
I'm doing this **only** onClick() thats why I don't get why it's actuelly happening on other entries too.
One thing I notices is: It seems to be only the "drawing"-part because the item which get selected "by it self" has still the **selected** value on **false**

I think it seems to have something to do with the reuse of the views in the custom ListAdapters getView(...)

**Code of onClick() in ListActivity:**

```
@Override
    protected ViewHolder createHolder(View v) {

        // createHolder will be called only as long, as the ListView is not
        // filled

        TextView title = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_title_channel_list_adapter);
        TextView content = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_content_channel_list_adapter);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.icon_channel_list_adapter);

        if (title == null || content == null || icon == null) {
            Log.e("ERROR on findViewById",
                    "Couldn't find Title, Content or Icon");
        }
        ViewHolder mvh = new MyViewHolder(title, content, icon);

        // We make the views become clickable
        // so, it is not necessary to use the android:clickable attribute in
        // XML

        v.setOnClickListener(new ChannelListAdapter.OnClickListener(mvh) {

            public void onClick(View v, ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                // we toggle the enabled state and also switch the the
                // background
                MyViewHolder mvh = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;
                Channel ch = (Channel) mvh.data;
                ch.setSelected(!ch.getSelected()); // toggle

                if (ch.getSelected()) {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_blue_selected);
                } else {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_blue);
                }
                // TESTING
                Log.d("onClick() Channel", "onClick() Channel: "
                        + ch.getTitle() + " selected: " + ch.getSelected());
            }
        });
return mvh;
    }
```

**Code of getView(...):**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    // When view is not null, we can reuse it directly, there is no need
    // to reinflate it.
    // We only inflate a new View when the view supplied by ListView is
    // null.
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(mViewId, null);

        // call own implementation
        holder = createHolder(view);

        // TEST
        // we set the holder as tag
        view.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        // get holder back...much faster than inflate
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // we must update the object's reference
    holder.data = getItem(position);

            // <EDIT SOLUTION>

    if(getItem(position).get_id() == channelList.get(position).get_id()){
        if(getItem(position).getSelected())
        {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_blue_selected);
        }
        else{
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_blue);
        }
    }

            // </EDIT SOLUTION>

    // call the own implementation
    bindHolder(holder);

    return view;
}
```

I really would appreciate any idea how to solve this! :)

If more information is needed please tell me.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me show you the code that I use for every `ListView` and properly controlling the click event for changing the background and doing anything further

```
public class Offices extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;

    /* selectedListItem will contain the number of items to be selected.
     * Your list item OnOlickListener will simply change this variable
     * to the position of the clicked item. The Adapter will do the rest 
     * because you need to refresh the ListView.
     */ 
    private int selectedListItem = -1;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private Vector<String> data; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.officeslayout);
        data = new Vector<String>();

        // Add data as per your requirement   
        data.add("one");
        data.add("two");
        data.add("three");
        data.add("four");
        data.add("Five");
        data.add("Six");
        data.add("Seven");
        data.add("Eight");
        data.add("Nine");
        data.add("Ten");

        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        listView.setDivider(null);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                selectedListItem = position;
                ((EfficientAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // call any new activity here or do any thing you want here         

                    }
               }, 200L);
            }
        });

        listView.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(getApplicationContext()));   
    }

    private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null || convertView.getTag() == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.officeslistitemlayout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.backgroundView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.OfficesBackground);
                holder.officesTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.OfficesName);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            if(position == selectedListItem) {  
                 holder.backgroundView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.and_gray_bg_listing_selected);
            } else {
                 holder.backgroundView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.and_gray_bg_listing);
            }

            holder.officesTitle.setText(data.get(position)); 

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView officesTitle;
        ImageView backgroundView;
    }

}
```

---

officeslistitemlayout.xml file will be like following add drawable and design it according to you put the following code in RelativeLayout

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/OfficesBackground" android:layout_width="fill_parent"       
            android:layout_height="45dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   
            android:background="@drawable/and_gray_bg_listing"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            ></ImageView>


         <TextView android:id="@+id/OfficesName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                   android:text="Offices Name" 
                   android:textColor="#000000" android:textStyle="bold"  
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            ></TextView>
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: Am I correct that maybe it is just because I missed that part:  

if(position == selectedListItem)
         {  

      holder.backgrouundView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.and_gray_bg_listing_selected);

         }   
         else
         {

      holder.backgrouundView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.and_gray_bg_listing);

             }
  
?  
I'm at work atm so I can't try it... but I will as soon as I am at home.
Thank you so long :)

Comment: Yes , you just need to perform this check in getView method .. rest things will be done automatically

Comment: Using this method we can draw any listview very smoothly and can control further event as well.. Using this i even implemented the animated delete functionality of iPhone TableView .. red delete button and other stuff

Comment: Ok i'll see how it works :)
Can u provide a good tutorial for the animation stuff? I never used it before...

Comment: You are the man! :D Why didn't I ask before... would have saved me a lot of time ^^
I had to modify your solution because my holder is holding a generic Object object.
I added my modification to the source on the question :)

Comment: Thank You Brother.
You can control everything in the getView Method..
Adding individual animation or any thing on any item of the listitem.
in short total control....

I will soon post a blog for adding animation easily on list item..
I will notify you then  :)

Comment: This is wrong in so many aspects and was so badly formatted that my eyes were crying blood.

Comment: Its solves my aspects and i shared my aspects resolution so it can help others in their aspects. Answer here should be considered a possible way to proceed on, rather expecting unique answer to question.... This is my perception :)