# How to get ListView to display correctly after onClickListener is clicked?

Tags: android, listview

**UPDATE:**
I've decided to use the ExpandableListAdapter to accomplish this ...as this code is almost effectively an attempt to engineer what expandable listadapter already does.

---

I'm using the standard pattern of ViewHolder in order to make ListView simply work...

`public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View vi=convertView;
  ViewHolder holder;
  if( convertView == null ){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.expandButton=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.expand_button);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();`

However....I believe that inside of my onClickListener...something is going wrong.

`final String textData = texts[position];
 final ViewHolder holderFinal = holder;
 holder.expandButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 holder.expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     holderFinal.expandButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized);
     holderFinal.text.setText(textData);`

So, everything displays fine when scrolling back and forth....however, whenever one of the listitems is expanded, the final line above contains a textData that belongs to another row. How do I get the correct textData to work INSIDE the onCLick listener?

Comment: The 'else' clause in your first code block should surely be getting convertView.getTag(), not vi.getTag().

Comment: it is, and now more code is shown.

Comment: You're doing an onClick listener for each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was experimented the same issue, i resolve this problem doing each item object of the listview a static class, like this:

all the data necesary to display a row in the ListView i defined in a static class like this:

```
static class DataHolder{
        Drawable extIcon;
        String text;
        String quantity_text;
        Drawable icon;
        int progressBarVisible;
        int quantityTextVisible;
    }
```

then to create all rows i make this:

```
    ArrayList<DataHolder> data = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();
            for ( int i=0 ; i < activitys.length ; i++ ) {
                DataHolder item = new DataHolder();
    item.icon = icons[i];  //an icons array
                item.quantity_text = "";   //some text
                item.progressBarVisible = View.GONE;   //a status for a progress bar
//other data setting
    }
```

then my ArrayAdapter subclass:

```
class ActivityList extends ArrayAdapter<DataHolder>{

        public ActivityList(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DataHolder> objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(HomeActivity.this);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity_item, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeActivityText);
                holder.icon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeActivityIcon);
                holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeActivityQuantityPBar);
                holder.quantity_text = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeActivityQuantity);
                holder.extIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.homeActivityIconExtended);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText(getItem(position).text);
            holder.icon.setImageDrawable( getItem(position).icon );
            holder.quantity_text.setVisibility( getItem(position).quantityTextVisible );
            holder.quantity_text.setText( getItem(position).quantity_text );
            holder.progressBar.setVisibility( getItem(position).progressBarVisible  );
            holder.extIcon.setImageDrawable( getItem(position).extIcon );
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

finally i dont have a button on my list row view but i can do any operation on various context in this way, obtaining always the exact text.
(the listView field is the instance of ActivityList)
(SAVED_SEARCH is the list item position)

```
((ActivityList)listView.getAdapter()).getItem(SAVED_SEARCHED).progressBarVisible = View.GONE;
((ActivityList)listView.getAdapter()).getItem(SAVED_SEARCHED).quantity_text = "any text";
((ActivityList)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

sincerally hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try postInvalidate()ing the ViewHolder after click.

Comment: I postInvalidated the ViewHolder's IMAGE attritbute, but still getting incorrect values after I expand

Answer (score 0):

Hi look at my solution on a similar problem:

- [Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour)
  I'm using there the holder pattern too

Answer (score 0):

initialize int GlobalPostion as a global variable

> `GlobalPosition = position
>
>    holder.expandButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
>   int localPosition = GlobalPosition
>      @Override
>      public void onClick(View v) {
>
>        holderFinal.expandButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.expander_ic_maximized);
>        holderFinal.text.setText(""+texts[localPosition]);
>        }`

The problem is you are not getting the exact list position , if you are storing it in a global variable an then move to a local variable inside OnClick you can retain the position. 
I hope this will help you