# getting data from edittext placed in listview

Tags: android

i created a list with textview & edittext using holder... it look like

### Textview    Edittext

### Textview    Edittext

### Textview    Edittext

```
                       [button]
```

but i cant get the data from each every Edittext & whenever i add a data to any edittext data is swapped to other edittext automatically i can't control over it.My need is to transfer all the edittext data (which are given dynamically) to hash table or something while click a single button... can any one assist me.. hw to achieve it... assist with sample code...

this is my src file....

```
package org.me.androidapplication40;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class customlistview extends Activity {

 private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
 private LayoutInflater mInflater;

 public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
 mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

 }

 public int getCount() {
 return country.length;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
 return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ViewHolder holder;
 if (convertView == null) {
 convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview,parent,false);
 holder = new ViewHolder();
 holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
 holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
 holder.txt=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtbox);

 convertView.setTag(holder);
 } else {
 holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }

 holder.text.setText(curr[position]);
 holder.text2.setText(country[position]);
holder.txt.setText("");
 return convertView;
 }

 public class ViewHolder {
 TextView text;
 TextView text2;
 EditText txt;
 }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
 l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

 }

 private static final String[] country = { "item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"};
 private static final String[] curr = { "1","2","3","4","5","6"};

}
```

---

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="left|center"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:paddingBottom="5px"
 android:paddingTop="5px"
 android:paddingLeft="5px">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:background="@drawable/bg"
 android:textColor="#FFFF00"
 android:text="hi"></TextView>
 <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02"
 android:id="@+id/TextView02"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
 android:textColor="#0099CC"></TextView>
 <EditText
android:id="@+id/txtbox"
android:layout_width="63px"
android:layout_height="30px"
android:textSize="12sp"
android:layout_x="211px"
android:layout_y="13px"
>
</EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="List of items"
android:textStyle="normal|bold"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
 <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent">
 </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: kindly assist as soon as possible

Comment: btw. you should accept the questions which had a solution, in order to make people want to help you! It's kinda apreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do is take whole holder of view in hasmap or any collection and get postion and retrive whenever its required.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to the one I had here:

[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour)

I think you are missing to update your reference like:

```
// we must update the object's reference
holder.data = getItem(position);
```

In this case the items are in list and `getItem(position);` is returning the object I actually want to get updated in a specific row.
Out of the box the listView recycles the views, that means the view which is disapearing while scrolling gets reused for the one which becomes visible. In order to get the correct data displayed you have to update your references.

U got what I mean? Or should I explain in other way?

Hope this helps!