# problem- Auto rearranging listview

Tags: android

i have a Listview with Textview & Edittext widgets.. listview rows are sorting / rearranging automatically when ever i click the "EditText" of any row.. how can i overcome this problem.. kindly assist me to toggle that this sorting problem

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this something similar to this:
[getting data from edittext placed in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781098/getting-data-from-edittext-placed-in-listview/4781839#4781839)

You should solve some things before asking x questions at the same time.
**And if you solved other stuff mark it as solved!**