# Android - updating the simpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a `ListActivity` which gets its data from a database query. I also have a custom adapter which extends simple cursor adapter.

To show the customised content, I have overridden the `newView` and bindView methods.

Each element of the view has:

1. `TextView` containing a title
2. `ImageView` containing number of stars - the image shown is changed based on a value obtained from the database
3. A button - the button text changes on clicks (Favourite/Make Favourite), and triggers a database update event.

My problem is this -  when I scroll the `ListView`, the changes I made seem to disappear .. for instance, the first item is marked favourite, and the list is scrolled ... when I come back to the first item, the text reverts back to its previous value, although internally the db has been updated.

I read that the `notifyDatasetChanged()` is not right for this case as the adapter should be notified of the database changes. I am trying to use the `reQuery()` method, but do not know where to place it.

Should I place the `reQuery()` in the `onClick` method of the button? If not, where should it be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What so ever Adapter is you are using must have getView Method.. Whenever a list is scrolled this getView Method got called for all the listItem in the view. Make Sure in the getView Method. That the view is getting generated dynamically.

It should check for clicked or changed value.

to update the list without scrolling your have to call listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()

Check the following link. here i mentioned a complete code to use listview properly. Using this we can achieve any listview behavior. We can embed animation also.

[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour)

Hope this help :)

Comment: thanks, was really helpful, it helped me solve some other issues, but i still have the same problem, i.e the adapter does not know that the view has changed. This is what my code does, the change is a database change - i.e a view element has an embedded button, and the button click changes a value in the DB.

closing and reopening the activity shows the database correctly updated, but not in realtime. 

My activity class extends ListActivity

Comment: i also implemented a listView with a delete button which on clicking delete the row data from the database and listview get updated after this. I never use any activity that extend ListActivity. instead i always embed list view in activity.This is personal preference but sometime it resolves some issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have extended BaseAdapter , 
after data is changed call , listView.setAdapter() and in getView() , update the view's data too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SetListAdapter` with `ArrayAdapter` to display the list. Use `ConvertView` to avoid inflating `View`.

```
if (convertView==null)
{
     //inflate your list
}
```