# Displaying ArrayList in ListView

Tags: android

I know my question isn't formulated well.

I'm adding items to an ArrayList downloaded from JSON file and the ArrayList is passed to a ListView.

**So what is my problem?**

After displaying the data from the ArrayList i wan't to add new items to it so they can be show right after they are added. I managed to do this by setting the Adapter for the ListView again after the data is added.
Displaying the new items should look smooth but instead it looks very sluggish and i know it's not the right way to do this.

I've searched about this problem but couldn't manage to find anything, so for anyone answering
**Thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy

You need not to set the data adapter again to the listview..
instead

call after you downloaded the new data

listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

this function will tell the  view to be build again.

In addition Check the following link. here i mentioned a complete code to use listview properly.
Using this we can achieve any listview behavior. We can embed animation also.

[[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)

Hope this help :)

Comment: **Thanks alot.**  Because of the lower case 's' in `notifyDatasetChanged()` i've lost few minutes :)  Edit it because somebody else maybe won't notice it too.

Comment: accept the answer if it helps you out so that others can get the right reference