# ListView - Set Minimum Height so that it always allows Scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I'm currently implementing Pull To Refresh functionality in Android. Now I have it working by creating a custom ListView using Header Views above the list items. In essence: when the top header view is in view, a refresh is started via a listener.

On starting the ListView, it automatically scrolls itself below the HeaderViews, hiding them until the user scrolls down. This works great when the the height of List Items exceeds the height the ListView itself (therefore there is scrolling), but when the Height of the Children is less than the height of the ListView, there is no scrolling and HeaderViews are forced to be shown.

Basically what I'm after is a way to force the Scrolling region of the ListView to be at least the height of the ListView + height of my HeaderViews. I've already got the height of my HeaderViews, I just can't find a way of getting the actual height of the ListView (i.e. when fill_parent is used) and a way of setting the minimum scrolling height. Any ideas?

*This will be released on GitHub after I'm finished it, and works on Android 1.5+.*

Comment: Just a note to say thanks for your GitHub release.  Saved me the time of having to fix all the issues with the Nilsson implementation!  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this myself by by adding a footerView to a large enough size:

```
final int numberHeaderViewsForPullToRefresh = 2;


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, final int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    if (this.getCount() > numberHeaderViewsForPullToRefresh) {

        // This is from Droid-Fu. Converts dip to px
        final int size = DisplaySupport.dipToPx(getContext(), 60);
        int childViewHeight = (this.getCount() - numberHeaderViewsForPullToRefresh) * size;

        Utils.writeLog("Child Views Height: " + childViewHeight);

        if (childViewHeight < h) {
            this.removeFooterView(footerPad);
            footerPad.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, h - childViewHeight));
            this.addFooterView(footerPad, null, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same but got it totaly resolved ...

I didnt set any header or footer to my listview instead i increase the total list item count by 2

say i have 10 list item then my list show me 12 views..

while inflating the view in the adapters getView() method i check for the position and inflate header and footer view for first and last position . for rest i apply my required view on list item .. this is sure shot solution for me.

and it worked too check the following link in this i wrote a code to use list view properly.

[[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)

in this code you will find a getView mathod make it inflate different view for header , footer , and rest list

If you do it then its ok, else i will put some more light to it..

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question. The problem is when I only have one or two items in my list, the list isn't long enough to scroll, therefore the are always shown. I need to extend the list so that there is enough space for the list to scroll and hide the headerviews.

Comment: this solution will actualy make the header and footer scrollable along the listview..
OK so you want list with less item to scroll ?

Comment: HeaderViews can scroll when you add them via `addHeaderView` anyway. I I want the ListView to always scroll.

Comment: implement TouchEvent Listeners and apply core animation.. keep this as last door to open