# overlapping problem in AdapterView

Tags: android

I am using `AdapterView` to have Custom List. But my Xml layout not only
contains that List. It also have some other elements like TextBox,
labels, ImageButton at the top and bottom.   so when i scroll it up
and animation starts it also draw elements on that Top Part(Which
contains ImageButton and other stuff). so can some one tell me how can
i remove it ? another issue is it do not have scrool bar. can some one
tell me how can i add scroll bar in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for adding scroll bar to the listView add this attribute to your listview in the xml
  
 android:scrollbars="vertical"

Check the following link. here i mentioned a complete code to use listview properly. Using this we can achieve any listview behavior. We can embed animation also.

For controlling list View Behavior ensure the getView Method of your list is generating the vew dynamically and as per your requirements . Each time a list get scrolled .  The getView Method get called for all the element in the view. Do account all these things.

[[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)

Hope this help :)