# Dynamically generating a List View with header

Tags: android

I am trying to generate a ListView with a header using the data received during runtime. In the constructor of my ListAdapter which extends an ArrayAdapter I am doing the following:

```
textViews = new TextView[tableHeaders.size()];
    for (int index = 0; index < tableHeaders.size(); index++) {
        textViews[index] = new TextView(context);
        textViews[index].setWidth((((TableHeaderValues) tableHeaders
        .elementAt(index)).getHeaderWidth() * width) / 100);
        textViews[index].setSingleLine();
        linearLayout.addView(textViews[index]);
    }
```

In my getview() method I set the text for each of the text view and I return the LinearLayout. However my output does not display all the rows. Suppose I have 3 rows, it displays only the second row and the other two rows are not visible. What could be the possible reason? Can someone kindly suggest me a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally prefer to  use efficient adapter.

Check the link here

[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)

Comment: in the getView Method for different position say for 0 and the last return different inflated view for header and footer... we can make it return any number of views and of different  layout for any cell

Comment: Hello, Thank you. Instead of creating the views from the code i inflated them from the xml file and it worked fine for me.

Comment: accept the answer if it helps you out. by checking the arrow on left side on answer. It will be a reference for some one else as well.