# Force close when I try to add items to xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created a series of listview in my app using a basic listview format as below, I am trying to add a border and a header to each of the listviews but whenever I try to add anything to the xml it force closes, I have tried textview framelayout nothing works, can anyone help with this?

```
package com.ff.org.p;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ff.org.R;
import com.ff.org.prrums.Anforums;
import com.ff.org.preps.Locare;

public class Ar extends ListActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
        String[] names = new String[] { "Forums", "Visitor Info", "Travel", "History", "Live Text" };
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        lv.setCacheColorHint(00000000);

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, names));
    }

    // Get the item that was clicked
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (position == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Arsenforums.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (position == 1) {

            String url = "http://www.ide.com/nal/";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Locarse.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:textColor="@color/black"
  android:textSize="21sp">
</TextView>
```

Any one help with this

Answer (score 0):

Check This

[Dynamically generating a List View with header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076084/dyncamically-generating-a-list-view-with-header/5076162#5076162)

Comment: Sorry this does not help I dont understand how this is done I need something simpler

Comment: try copy and paste of the code and see the result and try to analyse.. it seems the easiest to me as i am in full control what view is returning and how many. i had make not only simple using this even complex and animation embedded list view .