# Can't select specific objects in custom list - Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

I'm building an Android program that includes a custom list view.
The list itself works fine, and each object(row) contains one text view and one image.

I want that a different action will be carried out when the user is pressing each of the widgets.

What actually happens is that when the user is pressing the row, the whole row is being selected, and I can't figure out what he chose.
I've looked through a lot of guides, and couldn't find a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What so adapter you are using to set the listview must have a getView Method.
In the getView method all the view are set to return a single cell view. set the onclick listener of elements in the getView method individualy for each of your text view and image to set any flag or do what ever you want to do.
 .

check this link also for listview

[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)

in this within the getView method do something like

```
  holder.officesTitle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        do here what you want to do on item specific text click  

        }
    });
```

Hope this help and you can modify it according to your need