# Strange behavior of in List View click with Section Header

Tags: android, list, onclick, sectionheader

I am having a Custom List view with Section Header.

Note: this is not ordinary list. It's a Section Header.

Custom List is as follows:

[image: Custom List]

[image]

Before clicking the like image it looks like Image 1 and after click it should changed like Image 2.

My problem is that:

1. It looks very strange if I click on the like image of particular row Like image in others rows get changed.
2. Some times it throws Null Pointer exception if i click 1st row of the list.

What I need is that if I click on the Like image of particular list it state or color only change, others should keep unchanged.

[Main Activty link](http://pastie.org/2085800)

[List_Data](http://pastie.org/2085802)

[Custom List](http://pastie.org/2085803)

I tried with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479) but it doesn't help me.

Since it is Sectioned header, Adapter calculates the Header also as row so the size of list includes the Header also. Make a notes in this also.

Comment: if you r playing with list header then please android document for addHeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. for click listener

```
holder.like_icon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

@Override 
public void onClick(View arg0) { 
ViewHolder VH = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 
VH.like_icon.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on); 

} 
});
```