# onListItemClick in a class that is extending Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listener

I am trying to implement item click listener on my list in my main class that extends `Activity`, because for some reason if i extend `ListActivity` and expand my list with `setListAdapter`, the app force closes on startup, but if i extend Activity and expand it with `setAdapter` it runs fine.

Now my problem is i cannot find a way to implement a click listener for my list,  I have tried implementing it in the custom `ListAdapter`.

The list clicks are going to open another activity which has another list.

**------Updated------**

```
@Override
public void run() {
     // call any new activity here or do any thing you want here
     final Intent intent = new Intent();                       
     if(selectedListItem == 0) {
         intent.putExtra("value1", "value1");
         intent.setClass(this,    com.lister.listexample.ListexampleActivity.class);
     }
     startActivityForResult(intent, selectedListItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Change ListView background - strange behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strage-behaviour/4583479#4583479)

check the above link where i mentioned a list example. that will enable you to trick down your list problems.

Try making a sample project first by copy pasting the above example. then you will be able to understand the answer better

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yea, that might take a while to implement in my code, why is the "data" variable not defined is it a typo or am i missing something?

Comment: yes data you need to define. code example was just to give direction.

Comment: so i could use my arrays instead right? because i have no idea what Vectors are.

Comment: Yes sure.. i used in that example ArrayList<String> data ; for example. Go for that first. let me know if i can assist you more

Comment: okay, i updated my original post with me trying to call a new activity, it says that "setClass in the intent type is not applicable for the arguments", my first time dealing with Handlers, Runnable, so not too sure how they work.

Comment: is the copy paste of my example is running on to your end

Comment: yes it is working, thanks for all your help, i just had to change the "this" to "getApplicationContext()" in the setClass arguments!