# listview select multiple row

Tags: android, listview, multiple-select

I am using an `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The problem is when I select first item from `listview` it select another item automatically.

[image]

I didn't select item 12

[image]

All code

```
final ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

Product[] items = {
        new Product(1, "Milk", 21.50),
        new Product(2, "Butter", 15.99),
        new Product(3, "Yogurt", 14.90),
        new Product(4, "Toothpaste", 7.99),
        new Product(5, "Ice Cream", 10.00),
        new Product(6, "Milk", 21.50),
        new Product(7, "Butter", 15.99),
        new Product(8, "Yogurt", 14.90),
        new Product(9, "Toothpaste", 7.99),
        new Product(10, "Ice Cream", 10.00),
        new Product(11, "Milk", 21.50),
        new Product(12, "Butter", 15.99),
        new Product(13, "Yogurt", 14.90),
        new Product(14, "Toothpaste", 7.99),
        new Product(15, "Ice Cream", 10.00),
        new Product(16, "Milk", 21.50),
        new Product(17, "Butter", 15.99),
        new Product(18, "Yogurt", 14.90),
        new Product(19, "Toothpaste", 7.99),
        new Product(20, "Ice Cream", 10.00),
};

ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

         String item = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
         view.setSelected(true);
         listView1.setItemChecked(position, true);
         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
      }
});
```

Comment: can you post your adapter code

Comment: View re-usability. Use `ViewHolder`

Comment: try using parent.setSelection(int position) instead

Comment: Does this appearing when you scroll?

Comment: when i do down i see another item selected

Comment: Possible repeat question of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583349/change-listview-background-strange-behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `CustomArrayAdapter` shared at link http://paste.ubuntu.com/14848762/ , you are changing color of `relativeLayout` on `Click Listener`, when you scroll or view is recycled, you should reset this layout and should enable color for the item you clicked. You can for example use this approach.

```
relativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int color;
                    if (tt8.getText().toString().equals("1")){
                        color = Color.RED;
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    }else {
                        color = Color.GREEN;                        
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
                    }
                    p.setColor(color);

                }
            });

relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(p.getColor());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think thats it 1 minute :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your adapter reuses the inflated views.

One solution is to override your `ArrayAdapter's` `getView()` method in order to properly render your views and (even better) implement a `ViewHolder` so that your don't loose any performance by inflating again and again!

Comment: Well, remove the `relativeLayout.setOnClickListener` .... code inside the `getView`. Keep the `listView1.setOnItemClickListener()` of your original post. Everytime `setOnItemClickListener` is called keep in an array of booleans the click state. When your `getView` is called check the array of booleans an properly render RED or GREEN

Comment: That's for sure that your recycled view is not being reset. When you click the first item, this view will also be used for the 11th item as well. that's why your 11th item is also green.

Comment: @MustansarSaeed Totally agree

Comment: @Mustansar Saeed  absolutely

Answer (score -1):

Try to make this change

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            String item = listView1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Log.d("position", position+", item");


        }
    });
```

Update the value you got in logcat in the comment below so that i can suggest a better code.

Comment: The problem of OP is different. Issue is related to the view recycling and resetting.

Comment: But your View view will provide the reference to the current item selected, if the problem was not of the output, even then it must not jump to unexpected index. I feel the problem is with setting the adapter for the listview

Comment: Its not jumping to the unexpected index. The thing is when it selects the 1st item, this view is being used for the 11th item as well, that's why 2 items are being show green. This recycling can be managed by implementing custom arrayadapter and getView

Comment: when i do some up and down in listview mix items for example selected items are no longer selected ......

Comment: Why dont you you prefer item selected listener